# Get the non repeated item form list in Python

Tags: python-3.x, list

```
list1=[1,1,2,3,3]
```

from this list ,
we have to print unique number 2.
In python how to write the code*

```
lt=[1,1,2,3,3]
new_lt=[]
for i in  lt:
    if i not in new_lt:
        new_lt.append(i)
print(new_lt)
```

the above code output is:

```
[1,2,3]
```

So,I want to get exact output 2

thanks in advance

Comment: can you please add the code you have tried write so far?

Comment: try to complete your homework by yourself first.

Comment: @yedpodtrzitko,
lt=[1,1,2,3,3]
new_lt=[]
for i in  lt:
    if i not in new_lt:
        new_lt.append(i)
print(new_lt)


here ouput is [1,2,3]
but i want print only  2

Answer (score 1):

Your current code is getting all the values that occur in `lt` at least once. A few approaches you should try:

- Tracking the count of each number in the list. You can then use this count to figure out which element is not repeating.
- Generate a list of elements that occur more than once in the list. Then compare it with your initial list. Any element thats in your initial list and not in the new list occurs only once.